# E0119 error with generic trait implementation

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have an enum:

```
enum Field {
    Str(String),
    Integer(i64),
}
```

I want to do:

```
impl From<String> for Field {
    fn from(s: String) -> Field {
        Field::Str(s)
    }
}

impl<I> From<I> for Field where I: Into<i64> + Copy {
    fn from(i: I) -> Field {
        Field::Integer(Into::<i64>::into(i))
    }
}
```

This code above has an error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait
`std::convert::From<std::string::String>` for type `Field`:
--> <anon>:12:5
   |
6  |          impl From<String> for Field {
   |  ________- starting here...
7  | |       fn from(s: String) -> Field {
8  | |         Field::Str(s)
9  | |       }
10 | |     }
   | |_____- ...ending here: first implementation here
11 | 
12 |       impl<I> From<I> for Field where I: Into<i64> + Copy {
   |  _____^ starting here...
13 | |       fn from(i: I) -> Field {
14 | |         Field::Integer(Into::<i64>::into(i))
15 | |       }
16 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here: conflicting implementation for `Field`
```

`String` is not an implementor of `Into<i64>`, so why does error `E0119` happen?

Comment: Note: the `Copy` bound is superfluous here.

Comment: *`String` is not an implementor of `Into<i64>`* — not **now**, it isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR: `where` clauses don't count.**

---

The crux of the issue is that the conflict detection is *solely pattern based* at the moment: it does not account for `where` clauses.

The problem is 3-fold:

1. Deciding whether `where` clauses allow overlap or not is quite complicated,
2. Deciding which `where` clause is more specialized than another is quite complicated (upcoming specialization),
3. Allowing *negative reasoning* means that adding a trait implementation in the library code is now a breaking change.

The first two are purely implementation details, however the latter is a real concern in terms of language design. Imagine that:

- your code doesn't have the `Copy` bound,
- the Rust team decides to make parsing easier and add `impl Into<i64> for &str`.

And suddenly, there's a conflict where there was none before! You cannot upgrade!

So there's a real design choice here. You have to pick between:

- being able to write impl that do not conflict (yet),
- being able to upgrade your dependencies painlessly.

You can't have both.

---

*Note: try typing `Rust explain <code>` in your search engine of choice, and behold [E0119](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0119). Although it's not that helpful here.*

Comment: Or `cargo --explain e0119` or `rustc --explain e0119`